Concrete pyramidal base with threaded steel deck support
I saw a store-bought deck support recently that resembled this:


Roughly 2ft x 2ft concrete base
Threaded steel rod
Steel U-channel for holding two pieces of 2-inch wide lumber

What is this device called?
Not to be confused with a 4-way Deck Block.

I recall seeing something like that a few years ago. It was called the "Bigfoot deck support system."

@RMDman  Is it called that because you need bigfoot to move it?  My back is already complaining thinking about it.

Patio Drummond’s precast concrete Maxi-Base 



Are these any better than the 4-way deck blocks, other than being a little bigger?
